# Changing the locale settings of Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

I need to change the default paper size from "letter" to "A4"; to achieve this, I changed  the region settings in the Clock and region setting from the control panel. I am seeing the page size as Letter even if I restart the PC. Is there any other way to change this?

Answer (score 1):

You should check your NON-UNICODE language settings:
`Control Panel -> Regional and Language Options -> Administrative --> Change system locale`

Use the same setting as you use with 'Standards and Formats' which will 
probably be English (UK), and the result of the next printer installation 
should be a default A4 paper size. Unfortunately, you have to reinstall all 
printers after you changed the NON-unicode printers setting to automatically 
let them use the default A4 paper size.